# Successful combination of poll + answer approach to suggestions and discussions on Academia's meta

Tags: discussion, meta

Last week [a question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/do-we-need-a-women-tag) was posted on Academia's meta to ask the community whether we need the created [women](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) tag on site or not. As it was a discussion, I thought it may be a good idea to create a [poll like comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/do-we-need-a-women-tag#comment7296_1611) under the question to be able to have the statistics of the for and against of idea of having such tag on the site.

I think it was a good idea to have a combination of a poll and answers to such suggestions and discussions on meta. The reason is clear when we look at that question;

Not all the users have time or enough amount of reasoning to post a separate answer to the question. On the other hand, users can easily click to up-vote comments which had made like a poll under the question. Besides to allowing the users to easily express their ideas whether they are for or against the idea which is being discussed; having a clear result as poll to the suggestion will allow the moderators and users who have to make decision on the idea to decide with much more firm reasons, as they have clear number of votes whether the community likes the idea or not.

As a discussion and suggestion here, I want you to discuss whether the combination of a poll + answer to the suggestions and discussions are beneficial/productive for our website or not?

I also created [a poll](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/successful-combination-of-poll-answer-approach-to-suggestions-and-discussions#comment7309_1619) under this suggestion to allow users to easily vote whether they like the idea of having a poll under suggestions and discussions or not.

Comment: I **like** the idea of having a poll under the suggestions and discussions.

Comment: I **do not like** the idea of having a poll under the suggestions and discussions.

Answer (score 4):

I do not like the idea of a poll. While a poll will help determine the community consensus, it does not provide any means to understand the consensus. If we use your linked [question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/do-we-need-a-women-tag) as an example. With the poll we would simply know that AC.SE does not need a [women](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) tag, but with the highly up-voted answer we see:

> I strongly believe that a [women](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) tag is both duplicative of [gender](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) and counter-productive.

the answer then explains the issues.

To me that is way more valuable than simply knowing the answer. It is also the reason, that I felt that I needed to provide an answer to this question and not just vote.

Comment: Also, once answers exist, they can effectively act as a poll in any case...

Comment: But what I suggested is not a poll only, but decision making based on polls *and* answers together. Having a poll will not disturb the decisions at all.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent if "a poll will not disturb" (and I am not sure what disturb means in this sense) the decision, then I do not see the point of the poll at all.